# Why do I keep getting django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace although I added app name in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I have recently created a new app called newsletters, I have included it in the settings base.py and add it in the Main urls.py along with the app urls.py and added the app name as well, but i keep getting

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is
 not supported. Set the app_name attribute 
in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
```

I am not sure the reason here is the settings base.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'newsletters',
]
```

Here is the main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('newsletters/', include('newsletters.urls', namespace='newsletters')),
]
```

Here is the newseltters app urls.py

```
from .views import newsletter_signup, newsletter_unsubscribe

app_name = 'newsletters'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', include(newsletter_signup, namespace='newsletters')),
    path('unsubscribe/', include(newsletter_unsubscribe, namespace='unsubscribe')),
```

Comment: Your URL patterns are not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Include should be used when you want to include other app URLs, that's mostly used in global urls.py.

```
from .views import newsletter_signup, newsletter_unsubscribe
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', newsletter_signup, name="subscribe"),
    path('unsubscribe/', newsletter_unsubscribe, name='unsubscribe'),
]
```

This should fix the issue.